# show number to 100 decimal places

Tags: php, decimal, rounding

As an example I have code similar to this:

```
$r1 = 7.39999999999999;
$r2 = 10000;
echo bcmul($r1,$r2,100);
//returns 74000.0
echo ($r1*$r2);
//returns 74000.0
```

I am wanting it to return 73999.9999999999 rather than rounding it off.
Is there a formula or function to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The doc http://php.net/manual/de/function.bcmul.php says:

> left_operand: The left operand, as a string.
>
> right_operand: The right operand, as a string.

So use strings instead:

```
$r1 = "7.39999999999999";
$r2 = "10000";
echo bcmul($r1,$r2,100);
```

works.

Or if you have these varibales from somewhere cast them (via (string) ) to string. Maybe at this step you could encounter some roundings already...

Comment: That almost works, only when you cast them to a string `$r1 = (string)7.399999999` it automatically rounds it to 7.4.

Comment: As I said, there you could encounter the next problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a php person, but a quick Google suggests you may want the

```
$number_format()
```

function and specify the $decimals parameter. See [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: Nah, number_format throws a ton of random numbers `7.3999999999999896971303314785473048686981201171875000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: Those actually may not be random values. Are you aware that computers can only accurately approximate floating point numbers to a set precision, and after that you need to use special libraries to get better precision (like gmp library)

Comment: Indeed, with binary floating-point, What You See Is Not What You Get: the number that you (Robbie) specified as `7.39999999999999` isn't exactly representable as a double-precision binary float, so it gets replaced with the closest value that *is* exactly representable, which is precisely `7.3999999999999896971303314785473048686981201171875`. So those aren't random numbers at all - they're the exact digits of the number you're asking about.